# Neo4jPHP and CodeIgniter (Neo4j)

Tags: php, codeigniter, neo4j, codeigniter-2

How do you get Neo4jPHP to autoload as a library in CodeIgniter 2 ?

https://github.com/jadell/Neo4jPHP
http://codeigniter.com/

Neo4jPHP is a wrapper for the Neo4j SERVER REST API.

I have the Neo4j server running and used PHP to populate the DB with many nodes and relationships.

Next STEP - start using a more complete PHP abstraction of the REST API - Neo4jPHP

But, I'm stuck at auto loading Neo4jPHP as a library in CodeIgniter.

I added:
$autoload['libraries'] = array('Everyman/Neo4j');

And get:
An Error Was Encountered : "Unable to load the requested class: neo4j"

I'm pulling my hair out over what should be a simple step to get going...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm the author of Neo4jPHP.  I'm not that familiar with CI, but I worked up a quick blog post on a technique that I think might work.  Please let me know if it does not, or it needs to be improved.

http://blog.everymansoftware.com/2011/08/getting-neo4jphp-working-with.html

Comment: Thank you very much Josh! That works! Now we can get started :-)

Comment: @josh  I 've written a library by extending yours
https://github.com/asfandahmed/Neo4jPHP-lib-for-CodeIgniter

Answer (score 1):

From the [CI User Guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html):

```
File names must be capitalized. For example:  Myclass.php 
Class declarations must be capitalized. For example:  class Myclass
Classnames and file names must match.
```

That's why CI is trying to construct object for class Neo4j. I suggest you create a wrapper class for the Neo4j interface.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So linking it as a helper won't work also. That is terrible.